# Change to ternary in JSTL

Tags: jstl, ternary

Can you please help me to convert this JSTL tag to a JSTL ternary

```
<body
  <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${wcmMode.author}">class="author"</c:when>
    <c:otherwise>class="${page.class}"</c:otherwise>
  </c:choose>
>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's dead simple:

```
<body class="${ wcmMode.author ? 'author' : page.class }">
```